# How to get the schema for a specific JSON value?

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

As we all known, in oop language, we can know the type of an instance and type of the instance's properties.

I consider the JSON value is just like an instance of the JSON schema. So is there any solution to get the subschema of each JSON value?

For example, I have both the JSON Schema and JSON instance at hand as below:

```
{
    'definitions': {
        'img': {
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'url': {
                    'type': 'string'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'name': {
            'type':'string'
        },
        'avatar': {
            '$ref': '#/definitions/img'
        }
    }
}
```

And the JSON instance:

```
var json =
{
  'name': 'James',
  'avatar': {'url':'http://xxxx.jpg'}
}
```

How can I get the type of avatar is "img" when I access the json.avatar programmatically?

BTW, I'm using [JSON.Net Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema).

Answer (score 0):

The one important thing when trying to solve this problem is where and how Jschema is storing definitions and that you can move through schema similarly to JObject.

So, assuming you loaded schema like this (using Newtonsoft):

```
var schema = JSchema.Parse(@"{
                    'definitions': {
                        'img': {
                            'type': 'object',
                            'properties': {
                                'url': {
                                    'type': 'string'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': {
                        'name': {
                            'type':'string'
                        },
                        'avatar': {
                            '$ref': '#/definitions/img'
                        }
                    }
                }");
```

when accessing  *avatar* property of schema you will actually get already replaced link with definition (as Jschema is replacing it during parsing). But the definition itself is not lost, but stored in `schema.ExtensionData["definitions"]` - which was a surprise for me at the beginning - and you can access those definitions like standard JObjects.

With certain conditions (e.g having single definition with *url* token) you can access actual definition type:

```
        var avatarKey = schema.Properties["avatar"].Properties.Keys.Single(); //'url'
        var definitions = schema.ExtensionData["definitions"];
```

Then get definition containing *url* and get root name (*img* in your scenario):

```
        var matching = definitions.SelectTokens($"..{avatarKey}");
        var avatarDefinition = matching.Single().Root;
        var avatarType = (avatarDefinition.First() as JProperty).Name; //'img'
```

This is not an universal solution for every schema, but based on that you can adjust it to more sophisticated needs.